# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent Use of Select in Eagerly Loaded Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can get this to work using a select:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with('profile')
    ->get();
```

I'd like to only retrieve a couple keys in a user profile that is eagerly loaded.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with(['profile', function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
    }])->get();
```

Or:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with(['profile', function ($query) {
        $query->addSelect(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
    }])->get();
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and I get this error:

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 1034:
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

Thrown in /Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:

```
/**
 * Parse the nested relationships in a relation.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array   $results
 * @return array
 */
protected function parseNestedWith($name, $results)
{
    $progress = [];

    // If the relation has already been set on the result array, we will not set it
    // again, since that would override any constraints that were already placed
    // on the relationships. We will only set the ones that are not specified.
    foreach (explode('.', $name) as $segment) { // <--- line 1034
        $progress[] = $segment;

        if (! isset($results[$last = implode('.', $progress)])) {
            $results[$last] = function () {
                //
            };
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "addSelect" instead of "select" inside the eager load constraint closure

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with(['profile' => function($query) {
        $query->addSelect(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
    }])->get();
```

You have to include the foreign key on the addSelect otherwise nothing will be loaded

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but I get this error: `ErrorException in Builder.php line 1034:
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Comment: updated, i did not notice you are using array notation for eager loading

Comment: Oh man, you're a life saver!  I would never have figured out the foreign key column needed to be added, and I screwed up the array notation.  I was missing `=>`.